# How to keep a thread listening while the activity is not in the focus?

Tags: android, thread-safety, client-server, listener

I have a client program, inside that I have thread...
myClient {
myListener_In_a_THREAD( relevant function...  );
}

this_function_is_called_in_the_thread(...code that can listen to incoming text, and display);

Now...what I want is,

1. I am playing angry bird...
2. But, the program myClient should be able to listen to the incoming text...
3. If any text comes... it should be able to bring the interface forward! (or provide an option at least)

To achieve that, what should I do?
If you know, please explain and if you know, please give code example!

Thanks

Comment: use service not activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done using `Service` and `NotificationManager` classes.

Comment: myClient{ 


myListener_In_a_THREAD( relevant function... ); 


}


this_function_is_called_in_the_thread(...code that can listen to incoming text, and display);


Can you please give me a clue how to use this service with the code above?

Comment: At first you shouldn't show your activity when something happens. Usually apps create notifications in the status bar. So you create a service, start thread from it and create notification on some events. You can read more about services here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html. And some information about notifications: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.

Comment: Also, Selvin gave you a link in his comment. It'll be useful for you.